# Can I use @google-cloud/logging Node.js library to getEntries filtering by date?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I've got this code to `getEntries` from my project's cloud-logging.

```
import { Logging } from "@google-cloud/logging";

const PROJECT_ID = "XXXXX";

const logging = new Logging({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });

const getAdminLogEntries = async () => {
  const result = await logging.getEntries({
    filter: `logName="projects/XXXXX/logs/my-custom-log-name"`,
  });

  const entryList = result[0];
  for (const entry of entryList) {
    console.log(`entry.metadata: ${JSON.stringify(entry.metadata)}`);
    console.log(`entry.data: ${JSON.stringify(entry.data)}`);
    console.log(`---`);
  }
};

getAdminLogEntries();
```

But I'm only getting 6 results (the oldest one is from yesterday). And I guess it's because the query is not going too far back in time. Can it filter it by date? Ex: `from 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-31`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I've found out.

Reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#list_log_entries

I was able to filter by date with the following code:

```
import { Logging } from "@google-cloud/logging";

const PROJECT_ID = "XXXX";

const logging = new Logging({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });

const filterItems = [
  `logName="projects/XXXXX/logs/admin-logs"`,
  `timestamp >= "2021-02-01T00:00:00Z"`,
  `timestamp < "2021-03-01T00:00:00Z"`,
  `severity="WARNING"`,
];

// JOINING FILTERS WITH "AND" OPERATOR
const filters = filterItems.join(" AND ");

const getAdminLogEntries = async () => {
  const result = await logging.getEntries({
    filter: filters,
  });

  const entryList = result[0];
  for (const entry of entryList) {
    console.log(`entry.metadata.severity: ${JSON.stringify(entry.metadata.severity)}`);
    console.log(`entry.metadata.timestamp: ${JSON.stringify(entry.metadata.timestamp)}`);
    console.log(`entry.data.message: ${JSON.stringify(entry.data.message)}`);
    console.log(`---`);
  }
};

getAdminLogEntries();
```